# How to decrypt password which it is encrypted using generate_hash_password function in flask

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I use generate_password_hash flask function to hash password and save it to database

How can i unhash it again as a plain text to sent it as mail message to user who forget his/her password ?

Answer (score 3):

This can't be done, nor is it recommended.

A hash is by definition a one-way operation. You can hash a password, but it can't be unhashed into plain text.

The goal is to protect you as the server and database administrator so that if you are ever compromised and a bad actor takes your entire users table, they won't be able to determine those user's passwords.

The best strategy is to simply allow the user to reset their password, which is usually done by emailing them a one time use reset link containing a long randomly generated UUID (or equivalent) that they can use to temporarily authenticate and change their password.

Another strategy is that you can reset it for them and email them a temporary password that they will have to change on their next login, but the first method is better.

If a service ever sent me my own password in plain text, I would be very concerned!